# plotly python lines going backwards even after sorting values

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to create a plot which shows each individual's trajectory as well as the mean. This is working OK except that there appear to be extra lines and the lines go backwards, even after sorting the values.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                  "months": [0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3],
                  "outcome":[5,2,7,11,18,3,15,3]})

#sort by each individual and the months ie. time column
df.sort_values(by=["id", "months"], inplace=True)

#create mean to overlay on plot
grouped = df.groupby("months")["outcome"].mean().reset_index()

#create plot
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= df['months'], y= df['outcome'], name = "Individuals"))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=grouped['months'], y=grouped['outcome'], name = "Mean"))

fig.write_image("test.jpeg", scale = 2)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Now that I'm looking at it it actually looks like it's just creating one giant line for all IDs together, whereas I'd like one line for ID 1, and one line for ID2.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that you want to plot a **separate** line for each ID, so you should probably use a loop to group over the IDs and plot a separate line, or reshape the array so that you can plot [0,1,2,3] against [[Y10, Y11, Y12, Y13], [Y20, Y21, Y22, Y23]], (not [01,2,3,0,1,2,3] against [Y10, Y11, Y12, Y13, Y20, Y21, Y22, Y23])

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in your x-values. In Pycharm, I looked at the dataframe and it looks like this:

[image: pycharm.df]

Your months go from 0-3 and then back to 0-3. I'm a little unclear on what you want to do though - do you want to display only the ones with IDs that match? Such as all the ID with 1 and ID with 2?

Let us know what you expect to see given this dataframe I'm showing, it would be helpful.

*EDIT* So, I couldn't read the original question. Looking at it more, I believe I can at least answer the first portion however that led me to another bug. The line in question should be changed like so:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['months'][df['id'] == 1], y=df['outcome'][df['id'] == 1], name="Individuals"))
```

This will pull from the dataframe only where the id == 1, however this then won't show on your graph since your grouped dataframe doesn't fall within the same bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Yes so I have two individuals (ID 1, ID 2) and for each individual I have data at 0, 1, 2, and 3 months. I would like to plot each individual's data from 0-3 months. So the ideal plot would have outcome on the y axis, months on the x axis, and within the plot two blue lines (one for ID 1, one for ID2) and a red line for the mean.

Comment: @DrWampa I believe I got it, I couldn't read your original post. I'm going to edit my answer now.

Comment: Yes, looks like I may have to loop in that case (in reality have hundreds of individuals). Was wondering if there was a simpler way to do it but maybe not. Thanks for trying anyway!